# Why does struct variant_size; undefined in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

I saw `std::variant_size` when browsing [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant_size).

```
template <class T>
struct variant_size; /* undefined */    (1) (since C++17)
```

I saw here, `struct variant_size;` declare as **undefined**.

So, What is the reason to declare `struct variant_size;` undefined?

Comment: So you'll get a nice error when you try to use it on anything that isn't explicitly supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part you're looking at is the generic declaration for `variant_size`.
The actual definition of the `variant_size` are the specializations
defined below. Namely,

```
template <class... Types>
struct variant_size<std::variant<Types...>>
  : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Types)> {};
```

and the `cv`-qualifier specializations below that.